# Import private headers from Pod into Testing Target

Tags: testing, cocoapods, xctest

I have an Objective-C project that is distributed using CocoaPods, and the example project is configured with a Podfile so that it can test the installation of the library via CocoaPods. Here's the relevant part of the podspec:

```rb
s.default_subspec = 'Core'

s.subspec 'Core' do |sp|
    sp.source_files = 'Pod', 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
    sp.private_header_files = "Pod/Classes/Private/*.h"
end
```

Notice that I'm hiding some files in `Pod/Classes/Private` because I don't want to expose them as public API.

I have a Tests target in my Example project, and I'd like to import the files from `Pod/Classes/Private` into my tests so I can, well, test them.

How can I do this? Do I have to add a `Testing` subspec, and just hope no one uses it? If I try to `#import "SomePrivateHeader.h"` in my Testing target, I get a simple "file not found" error.

Note: I'm not trying to hide sensitive information. Just trying to protect users from implementation details.

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: No, but you could do what I do in [BonMot](https://github.com/Raizlabs/BonMot) and just not use CocoaPods in the example project. Just make a normal project, and in the CI script, lint the pod to make sure it compiles.

Comment: Ever reached an answer? For the time being, I just added my private headers directly into the Example project.

Comment: I second what I said before: don’t use the CocoaPods generated example project. Just maintain a project yourself, and use `pod lib lint` to make sure your pod still compiled when added to a project.